# how to reset the pointer of FILEREADER in java

Tags: java

there are two ways we can read a text file. first one is from the filereader and the second way is bufferedreader(which uses filereader only in its core). I was trying to implement a file reader from FILEREADER class. here is my implementation.

To read a line --

```
public static String readLine(FileReader fr) throws IOException {
    int i = fr.read();
    StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();
    while (i != 10 && i != -1) { // 10 for detecting new line and -1 for End of File
        strb.append(((char) i));
        i = fr.read();
    }
    String returnvalue = strb.toString();
    return returnvalue;
}
```

To read number of lines --

```
public static int readLines(FileReader fr) throws IOException {
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    while (!readLine(fr).isEmpty()) {
        numberOfLines++;
    }
    return numberOfLines;
}
```

and here is the main method --

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\files\\lines.txt";

    openFile(path);
    int total = readLines(fr);
    String[] str = new String[total];

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        str[i] = readLine(fr);
    }

    for (String s : str)
        System.out.print(s);
}
```

but the problem is when i am calling fr.readLines(Filereader fr) for the first time its taking the pointer of filereader to the end of file and then when i am doing fr.readLine(Filereader fr) its going into an infinite loop.

My question is -- 
How to reset the pointer of filereader to beginning of file again. ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'FLIEREADER in Java'. What are you talking about?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you implementing your own filereader just for fun, or are you trying to achieve something specific?

Comment: Or 'FILEREADER' either.

Comment: Sorry its filereader. its typo error. i corrected that one.

Comment: @kayaman its for practice. implementing own filereader.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading file to end of file, then every read after that returns end of file.

The only mystery here is why you're surprised. And why you're doing any of it. `BufferedReader` already exists, with a better `readLine()` method than yours, and you don't need to know the number or lines in advance: use a `Collection` to store them in, if indeed you really need all the lines of the file in memory at once, which is yet another poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need two separate methods to count no of lines and read each character from the file.

Use java.io.BufferedReader to do both read lines and count lines at the same time.

Regards
P